# FindAll WHERE using include with alias field in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

How to perform FindAll with WHERE using alias include association

Now I have this code :

```
 Photobook.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
      {
        attributes: ['full_name'],
        as: 'layouter_name',
        model: UserModel,
      },
      {
        attributes: ['full_name'],
        as: 'current_pic',
        model: UserModel,
      }
    ],
    where:{
       {
         '$current_pic.full_name$' : {
             $like: '%name%'
         }
      }
    }
 });
```

It doesn't work since the Photobook model don't have `current_pic.full_name` field. I just want to search the `current_pic` association instead of `layouter_name` association.

How to perform something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Photobook.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
      {
        attributes: ['full_name'],
        as: 'layouter_name',
        model: UserModel,
      },
      {
        attributes: ['full_name'],
        as: 'current_pic',
        model: UserModel,
        where: {
            full_name: {
                $like: '%name%'
            }
        },
        required: true
      }
    ]
 });
```

You can give where condition in the `include` array itself. `required: true` ensures that the `JOIN` is treated as `INNER JOIN`